# How do I emulate objdump --dwarf=decodedline in .bundle files?

Tags: c, macos, gdb, dwarf

I've been successfully using `objdump --dwarf=decodedline` to find the source location of each offset in a `.so` file on Linux.

Unfortunately on Mac-OS X. It seems that `.bundle` files (used as shared libraries) are not queriable in this manner.

I'm optimistic that there's something I can do, because `gdb` is able to correctly debug and step through code in these bundles — does anyone know what it's doing?

Further information:

The `dwarfdump` utility claims that the .bundle file contains no DWARF data, but that it does contain STABS data; however `objdump --stabs` cannot find any stabs data either.

(If it makes the question easier to answer, I don't actually need all of the offsets; being able to query the source location of any given offset would be good enough).

The bundle file I've been testing this on was generated using:

```
cc -dynamic -bundle -undefined suppress -flat_namespace -g -o c_location.bundle c_location.o -L. -L/Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib -L.     -lruby  -ldl -lobjc
```

The original c_location.o file does contain the necessary information for `objdump --dwarf=decodedline` to work.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that one way to do this is to use Apple's `nm -pa *.bundle` to find the symbol name and the original object file for a given offset.

Once you have that, you can first use `objdump -tT` to find the offset of the symbol name in the original object file; and then use `objdump --dwarf=decodedline` as before.

Each step requires a little bit of simplistic output parsing, but it does seem to work™. I'd be interested if there are more robust approaches.